# hibernate doesn't update id if another program updates the db

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

Lets say i have a spring + hibernate application which works fine together. One table A is managed by the application(CRUD). And there might be other programs which also insert some data into the table A. So here comes the problem.

For example: hibernate points the next id to 1001(auto_increment) and before it receives any data, i use a jar file to insert 100 records into the mysql db. So the next id to insert should be 1101 at the point. But if now hibernate receives a record and tries to insert, it throws a exception: java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Duplicate entry '1001' for key 'PRIMARY'. 
Could you please help? Thanks in advance!

ps: in hbm.xml:

```
<id name="cns_id" column="cns_id" type="long" access="field">
     <generator class="increment" />
</id>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [API](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/mapping.html#mapping-declaration-id), if you do this:

```
<id name="cns_id" column="cns_id" type="long" access="field">
     <generator class="guid" />
</id>
```

Hibernate should get the ID from the database:

> guid
>
> ```
> uses a database-generated GUID string on MS SQL Server and MySQL.
> ```

Comment: there might still be one problem because of the data type. if i use the guid, does that mean i can no longer use id as long?

Comment: @fe3o4: If the data is a GUID, when hibernate will query the database it should get a GUID. If on the other hand, you have stored your primary key as a Big Integer which increments, then you should get your integer value.